# compactness of a set on L2(0,1)

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization, compactness, lp-spaces

I am looking at a set of functions defined as follows

$ {\cal G}:=\{ g \in L^2(0,1) \;|\; g:\text{non-decreasing}, \int_0^1 g(\alpha)d\alpha = c_1, \int_0^1 g^2(\alpha)d\alpha=c_2\}$,
where $c_1\in \Re$ and $c_2>0$ are some fixed values.

Assuming that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are chosen such that the above set is not empty, and $c_2>0$, I am trying to prove whether the set is compact or not.

I have been trying different arguments, but they are all quite sketchy. I wonder if anyone can give me some ideas of how to prove or disprove this rigorously.

thank you!

Comment: If $c_2=0$ the set is compact or empty!  If $|c_1|>c_2^2$ or $c_2<0$ the set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Such a set cannot be compact.  Here is an example when $c_1=0, c_2 = 1.$
Then $\mathcal G$ contains all functions of form $$f_p(x)=\begin{cases} -\sqrt{\frac p{1-p}}& x\le p\\\sqrt{\frac{1-p}p}& x>p\end{cases},$$ for values of $p\in(0,1)$.  If $\mathcal G$ were compact, there would be a subsequence of $p_n\to0$ of the sequence $1/n$ such that the corresponding $f_n$ converged to some $L^2$ limit $f$.  What could $f$ limit be?  It has the property that $\langle f,g\rangle=0$ for all $g$ with support in $[0,a]$ for any $a<1$, as you can (and *should*) verify by evalutating $\lim \langle f_n,g\rangle$ for such $g$.  Since the set of such $g$ is dense in $L^2$ (I leave the *why* to you) we conclude that $f=0$.  But then $\|f-f_n\|=1$ for all $n$, contrary to $f_n\to f$.

The same trick works for other $c_1,c_2$ values.

Comment: I'm ticked off.  It is painful for me to write in mathjax, and your forgetfulness wasted my first answers' typing efforts.  I have modified my answer to fit your changed question.

Comment: It appears to me that if our discussion is based on weakly compact, then your argument shows that the set is not compact primarily because f=0 does not satisfy that $\int_0^1 g^2(\alpha)d\alpha = c_2$, but not so much about $||f-f_n||=1$,...?

Comment: Compactness is easier to come by in the weak topology, yes.  I would diagnose the problem in my example as a consequence of the norm function not being continuous in the weak topology.  Your set *is* relatively compact in the weak topology.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, which was based on a hasty reading and misunderstanding of what you had asked.  I believe your set $\mathcal G$ is relatively compact in the weak topology and have no beliefs at all about $\mathcal H$, which is a fishy kind of un-$L^2$ set to my eyes.  I advise you to put everything you know and want into a new question, so it can be addressed as a whole, not via comment-box dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now deleted some of my previous comments and summarized my points in the new question" Proving that a subset is compact in L2(0,1)" If you can help take a look, that will be much appreciated.